# Hook for altering the content of all wp mails

Tags: plugins, functions, filters, hooks

Hi i want to set email template for all mails for my site .
I know how to set up mail template and i set mail template for each of my mail by editing the code  ie

```
wp_mail( $recipient, $subject,  $body, $headers, $attachments );
```

is mail code then i replaced it with

```
ob_start();
             require_once (get_template_directory() . '/mail-templates/contacemail.php');
             $html2 = ob_get_contents(); 
        ob_end_clean();
            return wp_mail( $recipient, $subject,  $html2, $headers, $attachments );
```

now email template is set up for this mail.[here in contacemail.php echo $body; get the content of body]

Now i need to do for all my emails rather than editing this code for indivdual mails.
How to do that?
Is there any hook or filter available? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a filter for this.

The correct filter is `wp_mail` and is defined in [/wp-includes/pluggable.php Line 135](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L235)

So the code (maybe in your functions.php) should look something like this:

```
function mail_template($args){

    ob_start();
    require_once (get_template_directory() . '/mail-templates/contacemail.php');
    $args['message'] = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean();

    return $args;

}
add_filter('wp_mail', 'mail_template');
```